# How to Update Kubernetes Deployments + Services

Tags: deployment, kubernetes

I have put together a simple cluster with several deploys that interact nicely, dns works, etc. However, as I'm using Deployments, and I have a few questions that I could not find answered in the docs.

- How do I non-destructively update a deployment with a new copy of the deploy file? I've got edit and replace, but I'd really like to just pass in the file proper with it's changed fields (version, image, ports, etc.)
- What's the preferred way of exposing a deployment as a service? There's a standalone file, there's an expose command... anything else I should consider? Is it possible to bundle the service into the deployment file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I non-destructively update a deployment

You can use `kubectl replace` or `kubectl apply`.  Replace is a full replacement.  Apply tries to do a selective patch operation.

> What's the preferred way of exposing a deployment as a service?

All of your suggestions are valid.  Some people prefer a script, and for that `kubectl expose` is great.  Some people want more control and versioning, so YAML files + `kubectl apply` or `kubectl replace` are appropriate.  You can bundle multiple YAML "documents" into a single file, just join the blocks with "---" on a line by itself.